# MYSQL join bringing back triple results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm not amazing with mysql by any means. Until yesterday i haven't dealt with any kind of join and I'm now having problems with it.

The SQL Statement i am executing is as below:

```
SELECT `services`.`name`, `services`.`type`, 
`services`.`review_count_approved`, `reviews`.`escalate`,
`services`.`average_rating` 
FROM `services` 
INNER JOIN `reviews` on `services`.`serviceID` = `reviews`.`serviceID`       
WHERE `services`.`serviceID` IN (50707, 50709);
```

From doing this query it should only bring back 2 results, however it is actually bringing the 2 results back three times.

Okay so the two tables i am getting information from are

-services

-reviews

Now if i just do the following sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE `serviceID` IN  (50707,50709);
```

Its brings back these records

[image]

But when i do the top query on this post it brings back these 2 results 3 times.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: Why should you only get 2 results? You should get a result for every review of the two services.

Comment: @barmar very true i didnt think about that one, that explains why nothing comes back when there isnt a review next to it. How could i change this so that it gets me back just 1 service regardless if it has a review or not?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: If the reviews have different `escalate` or `average_rating`, do you really just want one of them? Which one?

Comment: You have just saved me :) thank you. I will research left and inner join now to see the differences

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Note that the answer you accepted will return multiple results for a service if they have different `escalate` or `average_rating`.

Comment: If you made an answer i would have accepted it, ive just changed the inner join to left join now so i should be all good to go thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have multiple serviceIDs in the reviews table. Use distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT `services`.`name`, `services`.`type`, 
`services`.`review_count_approved`, `reviews`.`escalate`,
`services`.`average_rating` 
FROM `services` 
INNER JOIN `reviews` on `services`.`serviceID` = `reviews`.`serviceID`       
WHERE `services`.`serviceID` IN (50707, 50709);
```

Comment: Now to figure out how i do that in laravel :)

Comment: now when i try to add another id like (50707,50709,50713) it just brings back the first 2 results?

Comment: @MatthewSmart Are there any reviews of `50713`?

Comment: @barmar there is not i just realised because of your other post. Im not sure how to go about this now because i still want to grab the service even if it doesnt have any review against it